# Fill password field in iTunes prompt on a UITest

Tags: swift, objective-c, uitest, skadnetwork

I am writing a UITest for my app.
While the test is running I get a 'Sign In to Complete Purchase' prompt:

[image]

I was able to fill the 'Apple ID' text field since the keyboard is already open and ready to fill it - To do it I used:

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
[app typeText:@"My iTunes username"];
```

But I could not simulate a tap on the password field. I could not figure out how to find it in the UI. I tried lots of options (but not of them worked):

```
XCUIElementQuery *collectionViewsQuery = app.collectionViews;
[collectionViewsQuery.textFields[@"password"] tap];
[collectionViewsQuery.textFields[@"Password"] tap];
[[collectionViewsQuery.textFields firstMatch] tap];
[collectionViewsQuery.secureTextFields[@"password"] tap];
[collectionViewsQuery.secureTextFields[@"Password"] tap];
[[collectionViewsQuery.secureTextFields firstMatch] tap];

XCUIApplication *springboard = [[XCUIApplication alloc] initWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.springboard"];
[[springboard.alerts firstMatch].textFields[@"password"] tap];
[[springboard.alerts firstMatch].textFields[@"Password"] tap];
```

I think that the real issue is the fact that I can't get the corresponding view (or collectionView in this case).
I tried looking in Apple documentation and I could not find anything.
I did see the option of adding a configuration file for In-App purchases testing but in my case I don't test In-App purchases. I download another app from within my app to check conversion value (SKAdNetwork) on AWS device farm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours I found the answer:

```
- (void)signInToItunes {
    XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
    [app typeText:@"YourAppleID"];
    sleep(2);

    [[app.secureTextFields firstMatch] tap];
    [app typeText:@"YourPassword"];
    sleep(2);
    
    [app.buttons[@"Sign In"] tap];
}
```